# How chroot works with .bashrc?

Tags: bash, chroot

I wrote some code in `.bashrc`, that is working as expected.

Here is the code,

```
if [[ -v X_CHROOT ]]; then
   PATH="/home/user/chroot_local/bin":$PATH
fi
```

Expectation is that `PATH` should be appended when I run the `chroot` command. And is appended as expected.

So, After logging on machine, before `chroot`, it is,

```
> echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:......
```

after `chroot`, it is,

```
> echo $PATH
/home/user/chroot_local/bin:/usr/local/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:......
```

My question is,

Amidst logging, `.bashrc` already executed.

On `chroot` command does `.bashrc` content again execute?

Comment: I guess that you proved that *it can*.  But you are not telling us how do you enter the chroot.  The coreutils' chroot will, by default invoke `/bin/sh`, which is likely to be bash on your system.  If `HOME` is not changed and is visible there's nothing holding bash from simply finding the `.bashrc` file.

Comment: @grochmal not telling because it is customized tool and I see shell msg after running chroot. Sorry about that

Comment: @grochmal Another question is, when you exit from `chroot`, how does environment change back which is equivalent to undoing `.bashrc` execution? For example, if `.bashrc` updates with new `PATH` on `chroot` then how does exiting from `chroot` I see old `PATH`. How does this work internally?

Comment: Each process holds its own environment in the `environ` global (which sits after the stack on most architectures together with `argv`).  All processes are started by fork+exec and one of the arguments to `exec` is the environment, which is often taken from the parent (process creating the other process) but does not need to be.  In any case, a child process will have its own copy of the environment in its memory space.  i.e. all environment inheritance always happen parent->child, and under no circumstance child->parent.